# Сортировка: вывести товары в порядке, заданном в массиве

Tags: массивы, php, сортировка

**Есть функция:**

```
function all_tovars() {
 $q = $db->query("SELECT `id`, `title` FROM `tovars` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
 $a = array(5, 1, 2);
 while($d = $db->fetch($q)) {
  $id = $d['id'];
  $title = $d['title'];

  $template .= 'ID товара: '.$id.'; Наименование товара: '.$title.' <hr /> ';
 }
 return $template;
}
```

`echo all_tovars();` выводит:

> ID товара: 1; Наименование товара:
> Первый товар
>
> ID товара: 2; Наименование товара:
> Второй товар
>
> ID товара: 5; Наименование товара:
> Пятый товар

В функции так же есть массив `$a = array(5, 1, 2);`. Как мне вывести товары в таком порядке, опираясь на массив `$a`?

> ID товара: 5; Наименование товара:
> Пятый товар
>
> ID товара: 1; Наименование товара:
> Первый товар
>
> ID товара: 2; Наименование товара:
> Второй товар

Comment: А откуда вы знаете правильную последовательность (5, 1, 2)? А если там 1000 товаров будет, то что?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select id, type, details from supportContacts ORDER BY Field(id, 3,1,2);
```

Код на [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab19e2/1)

Адаптация под ваш пример:

```
$a = array(5, 1, 2);
$q = $db->query("SELECT `id`, `title` FROM `tovars` ORDER BY FIELD(`id`," . implode(',', $a).")");
```